Rails route path helpers from inside namespaced controller
I have an app with a few top level models, all working. My layout views have a header partial, and this has the main nav links on a navbar, pretty standard stuff. Now I come to add some new functionality, and because there will be more later, I decided to encapsulate the new models and controllers in a namespace to keep the app tidy. Ok, when I come to try the first index view, it won't load. The error is No route matches {:action=>"index", :controller=>"electrical/roles", :locale=>:en} That's true, the route to "roles" does not go through the electrical namespace. The error is generated when the header partial is being evaluated. The .erb code for the link is the same as all my other views, which work. Is the path helper adding the namespace to the path because it is now being called from a view within that namespace? If so, how do I route out of the namespace? Or better still, can I tell it not to mess with my paths, and I'll explicitly tell it when I want a namespaced path?
In  /app/views/layouts/_header.html.erb:
<% if current_user.has_role? :admin %>
          <li class="nav-item">
            <%= link_to t('role', scope: 'activerecord.models').pluralize,
              roles_path,
              class: ['nav-link', { active: current_page?(controller: 'roles') }],
              aria: { label: t('role', scope: 'activerecord.models').pluralize } %>
          </li>
        <% end %>

In /config/routes.rb:
    Rails.application.routes.draw do
      scope "(:locale)", locale: /#{I18n.available_locales.join("|")}/ do
        get 'site/home'
...
        devise_for :users
        resources :users, :only => [:show, :index]
        resources :projects
        resources :tags
        resources :users, :only => [] do
          resources :roles, :only => [:destroy]
        end
        resources :roles, :only => [:index, :new, :create]
        namespace :electrical do
          resources :cable_types
...
          resources :cables
        end
      end
    
      # Defines the root path route ("/")
      root to: 'site#home'
    end


looks like :locale is required in route, so you should use roles_path(locale: I18n.locale)

I don't think locale is the issue. As I said, these links work correctly outside the namespaced views. It may be a clue though. In setting up the routes with locale, I followed the rails guide for i18n and included locale in default_url_options in the Application_Controller.

@AntonBogdanov (:locale) means that it's an optional segment - and the error message actually includes a locale. Sometimes just guessing wildly isn't helpful.

You're really reading way to much into the concept of namespace. namespace is just a shorthand for scope path: :foo, module: :foo and what it does is add a prefix to the path, the helper and expects the controller to be nested in a module. This in turn effects how the controller will look up views but it does not mean that the view knows that it's "in a namespace" and it should not effect how a simple call to a routing helper works. I think there is something missing from the picture here and the culprit may not be what you think.

Try isolating the issue by calling app._routes.url_helpers.roles_path from the console or by writing a routing test/spec.  Also check that the output from rails routes matches what you're expecting.

Also how are you reproducing the error? Does this occur when you visit the page (what page?) with a browser or is this possible a controller test/spec?

Thanks again for your help @max, much appreciated. Regarding your first comment, I'm not reading anything into the concept, I'm just trying to implement it and interpret the errors! I thought it would work the way you explain... In the console, app._routes.url_helpers.roles_path gives the expected answer /roles.  The error occurs when I visit the index page in a browser. The server log shows everything ticking along until it evaluates the link and then it throws the error.

I wonder if it's current_page?(controller: 'roles') that's causing it. That does use the current request as context and can behave somewhat unexpectedly. Can you add a breakpoint and test that theory?

Hey @max, that's it! You nailed it. A bit of a surprise for me, I was trying to get debug info on exactly where in that line the problem was occurring, without success. But just by removing the current_page check, the error went away. I'm not so bothered to have that functionality, I think our user will know what page they are on from other clues, but I am always interested to know what the syntax should be. Can you post your comment as an answer?

The most likely culprit is current_page?(controller: 'roles') it uses the current request as context and can give somewhat unexpected results when used in the older non-resource based way.
You can avoid this by just passing a string -current_page?(roles_path).
See:

https://api.rubyonrails.org/v7.1/classes/ActionView/Helpers/UrlHelper.html#method-i-current_page-3F


"Implicit Controller Namespacing" documented here https://api.rubyonrails.org/v7.2/classes/ActionView/RoutingUrlFor.html#method-i-url_for

I was trying to show that link as active whenever any of the controller actions was current, not just the index action.
